# Anyone recognise a full length novel about maybe 6 people who are each given device that can destroy or save the world?

Tags: story-identification, powers

My recollection is hazy but I think 6 or so individuals find themselves together briefly in  a remote part of the world. They represent different regions round the earth. Each is given something with the power to save or destroy humanity. The story then follows them as they are returned to the normal locations and grapple with their power and how to use it.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/264822/1960s-movie-alien-entity-gives-6-7-random-people-scatter-around-the-world-the

Comment: I think it could be the one. Can't be sure until I find and read it but this post could be deleted or am I meant to do that ?
That's now 4 out of 4 of my hazy recollections of nearly 60 years ago identified. That's almost science fiction itself.

Comment: It's not a duplicate because the other question is asking to identify a film.

Answer (score 9):

Could this be [The 27th Day](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/941703.The_27th_Day) (1956) by John Mantley?

> Five Earthlings, selected apparently at random by aliens, are each given the power to wipe out the human species. After 27 days, the power will evaporate & be gone forever. It's still the height of the Cold War. What would you do?

As an aside, this book was made into a [film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_27th_Day) in 1957.

Comment: One of those cases where the film is definitely better than the book, imo.