# Why did Jonathan Clark decide to come out of hiding?

Tags: the-27th-day

Thanks to [this ID Q&A](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/264822/31394), I recently found out about the film *The 27th Day* and watched it online:

Brief verdict: very interesting premise, some parts well made, but there was a lot of Cold War anti-Soviet propaganda, and the ending was a bit of a letdown for me. Anyway, my question is about Jonathan Clark (and Eve Wingate, but he seemed to be the main instigator of their actions during that period) and his period in hiding.

Why did he go into hiding in the first place? This made sense to me: just like the USSR government ruthlessly attempted to use Ivan Godofsky's capsules for war and world domination, the US government would be expected to act similarly with Jonathan Clark and his capsules. Knowing that warmongers controlled the world, he went into hiding so that nobody could find him and attempt to use his capsules for war, murder, and destruction.

But then, **why did he come out of hiding later in the film?** Did I misinterpret his reasons for hiding in the first place? Did he change his mind about the nature of his country's leaders (certainly he wasn't subjected to the same brutalities as Ivan Godofsky in the film)? Was it Eve Wingate's influence somehow (he made the decision, but did she say something that pushed him towards it)?

From an out-of-universe perspective, it makes sense that a 1950s American film might not be able to show the US and USSR governments as "equally bad" bunches of warmongers, but what was the in-universe reasoning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At around the 44 minute mark -- a few minutes before the scene where they give themselves up to the authorities -- Jonathan and Eve are listening to a news report on the radio about the ongoing search for Jonathan, which mentions the killing of a man fitting his description and alludes to people taking the law into their own hands. Eve tells Jonathan he's not to blame for the panic in the world, but he walks outside without saying a word, suggesting that he does feel guilty about the death of that man.

> RADIO ANNOUNCER: **The search for Jonathan Clark still goes on, without success. The federal authorities are repeating their warnings. People are not to take the law into their own hands. In the past 48 hours, one man answering the description of Jonathan Clark has already been killed.** Remember, Clark is only in contempt for refusal to obey a congressional summons to surrender to the authorities.
>
> EVE: You're no more to blame for the panic in the world than any of the rest of us. We all avoided our responsibility by running away from it.

Soon after, Eve finds Jonathan sitting alone outside and initiates a conversation with him, during which she asks him if he's thinking about giving himself up. He responds that he's not sure, but that it might stop some of the panic if he comes in of his own accord.

> EVE: **Are you thinking of giving yourself up?**
>
> JONATHAN: I don't know what to think anymore. **If I come in on my own accord, I might be able to stop some of the panic.**

They both give themselves up to the authorities in the following scene, so the motivation was presumably the one Jonathan articulated in the quote just above.